# how to store a time value in SQLite database in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to store a timevalue in an SQLite database in Android.  My time value is in EditText, and when I click the save button I would like the time value to be stored in the database.  And also I want to review the already-stored value in the database.

Comment: have you tried just storing it as a string?

Answer (score 6):

SQLite [doesn't have a specific datatype for storing times](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime), and leaves it up to you whether you want to store them as text, integers, or floating-point values, so you can establish whatever convention works best for you.

For your application where you want the time to be editable by the user I'd suggest looking into the [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html) and [TimePicker](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-timepicker.html) widgets, so that you don't have to worry about parsing and formatting the time as text, and then the Java [Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class for converting the data from those into a simple value that you can put in the database (I'd suggest using the [getTimeInMillis()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis()) method to convert it into a integer).

Comment: when we store time in milliseconds can later we use for alarm?

Comment: @BibiTahira Yes, I believe so. Don't forget that alarms have to be set in the UTC time zone.

Answer (score 3):

Sqlite + timestamp = [Date and time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Sqlite + timestamp + android = [Timestamp Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/Timestamp.html)

Other options

- create a column for each piece of info you wish to store (day, hour, min, second, etc)
- convert time into long and store that instead. Use java.sql.Time